# Database Benchmarks

Tags: open-source, project, benchmarking, database

I am working on a Graduation Project and wondering if anyone can help me with: Benchmark data to load and test on my application.
We are willing to compare between different designs and implementations of different database management systems, and I thought we shall use a standard data set for this task.
Is there any? and if yes, would you kindly show me where to find some, and if there are measures to consider, that would be really helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many standard benchmarks. The most famous are the TPC Benchmarks:

http://www.tpc.org/information/benchmarks.asp

Moreover, some researchers publish specific benchmarks. For example, O'Neil et al. avec proposed the [Star Schema Benchmark](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~poneil/StarSchemaB.pdf). You need a [small and free program](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~poneil/dbgen.zip) to generate the data.